# Clone div not being removed, just the original one

Tags: javascript

I have a div being cloned and I would like the button `remove` to remove the selected `div`. It's only removing the html div that is used to clone the field.

See my code below:

JS

// Clones Schedule Field

```
function cloneField(){
    const newFieldContainer = document.querySelector(".schedule-item").cloneNode(true)
    console.log(newFieldContainer)
    let fields = newFieldContainer.querySelectorAll('input')
    fields.forEach(function(field){
        field.value = ""
    })
    document.querySelector("#schedule-items").appendChild(newFieldContainer)
    

  
}
```

// Adds new field

```
function addButton(){
    let button = document.querySelector("#add-time")
    const selected = document.getElementById('select').selected
    let scheduleItems = document.querySelector('#schedule-items')
    let inputs = scheduleItems.querySelectorAll('input')
            if(selected == true || [...inputs].some(input=>input.value === "")){
            alert('Tem o dia ou a hora faltando nos Horários Disponíveis.')
            button.removeEventListener('click',cloneField)

        }else{            
            button.addEventListener('click',cloneField)
    }   
    }
```

// Removed field added if needed

```
let buttonRemove = document.querySelector('.remove-schedule-item')
buttonRemove.addEventListener('click',removeField)

function removeField(){
   
    let scheduleItem = document.querySelector('.schedule-item')  
    scheduleItem.parentNode.removeChild(scheduleItem);
    console.log('hey')

}
```

HTML

```
<fieldset id="schedule-items">
                    <legend>Horários disponíveis 
                        <button type="button" id="add-time" onclick="addButton()">+Novo horário</button>
                    </legend>
                    <div class="schedule-item">
                        <div class="select-block">
                            <label for="weekday">Dia da semana</label>
                            <select name="weekday[]" required="true">
                                <option id="select" value="select" selected>Selecione uma opção</option>
                                {%for weekday in weekdays %}
                                <option value="{{loop.index0}}">{{weekday}}</option>
                                {%endfor%}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-block">
                            <label for="time_from">Das</label>
                            <input type="time" name="time_from[]" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-block">
                            <label for="time_to">Ate</label>
                            <input type="time" name="time_to[]" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="remove-schedule-item">
                            <button>remove</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you try to remove the item

```
function removeField(){
   
    let scheduleItem = document.querySelector('.schedule-item')  
    scheduleItem.parentNode.removeChild(scheduleItem);
    console.log('hey')

}
```

you are always selecting the first `.schedule-item` and then delete the first item

edit:

when you clone you element you need to add event listener to the new element

```js
function cloneField(){
    const newFieldContainer = document.querySelector(".schedule-item").cloneNode(true);
    let fields = newFieldContainer.querySelectorAll('input')
    fields.forEach(function(field){
        field.value = ""
    });
    document.querySelector("#schedule-items").appendChild(newFieldContainer);
    const removeBtn = newFieldContainer.querySelector('.remove-schedule-item');
    if(removeBtn){
      removeBtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
        newFieldContainer.remove();
});
    }
    
}
```

Comment: and how can I select any item I click the remove button?